# What is the font on this fast-food banner?

Tags: font-identification, sans-serif

[image]

I tried the usual matcherators to no avail. The image is at an angle and there's  perspective too.

Comment: BTW - it most definitely does help when trying to use matcherate (or other such algorithmic service) to first perspective correct and crop such images - a pretty quick process in Photoshop or Affinity Photo.

[example corrected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9eTDX.jpg)

Answer (score 3):

The font is **Gotham** using various font weights.

[image: sample text]

Comment: @GeorgeDimitrov if that is the font then please mark this as the accepted answer.